# How to store large float numbers as-is in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, floating-point, numbers, decimal

I have a file contains some floating numbers. They are resulted from python's [process_time()](http://%20time.process_time()) function. This is one example of the values I want to store in a field,

```
0.0034867459908127785
```

I need to store the number as-is. Then I want to query `MAX` of the column. When I store the values in a column of type `FLOAT()` it gets rounded to: `0.00348675`. Then when I query MAX, I get: `0.0034867459908127785`
This is unacceptable in my case. I do not want any changes on the numbers.

How can I store these large floats as-is? then query MAX and get the exact number stored? I do not want MYSQL to round anything. I need the numbers intact.

Comment: Which mysql version you are using?

Comment: From what you wrote, it seems the value is being displayed as “0.00348675” but the full value is being stored. That is because, if the stored value were 0.00348675, querying the maximum would return 0.00348675. It could not return 0.0034867459908127785 if that value were not among the stored values. So likely, when you displayed the stored value, whatever formatting was used to display it showed only “0.00348675” even though the stored value was 0.0034867459908127785 (or something close to it). If this is not the case, you will have to be more specific about how you are getting these results.

Comment: Take a look at MySQL DECIMAL datatype with adequate precision and scale.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil I changed the field type from `FLOAT` to `DECIMAL(65,30)`. It seems to store longer than needed by adding zeros to the right. So my number becomes: `0.003486745990812778500000000000`. The max also return this number. Do I seem doing the right thing? If so, I will post this as an answer.

Comment: @Suresh I am using version `5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`

Comment: @user9371654 : check my answer

Comment: `FLOAT` is a 4-byte animal that can hold only about 7 significant digits; you seem to need about 17.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
**First Approch:**
```

You can save data as decimal and get max as :

```
CREATE TABLE `save_processtime1` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `point_decimal` DECIMAL(25,20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `save_processtime1` (`id`, `point_decimal`) VALUES('1','0.0034867459008127785');
INSERT INTO `save_processtime1` (`id`, `point_decimal`) VALUES('2','0.0034867459908127785');
INSERT INTO `save_processtime1` (`id`, `point_decimal`) VALUES('3','0.0034867459908127001');
INSERT INTO `save_processtime1` (`id`, `point_decimal`) VALUES('4','0.1000000021200021011');
INSERT INTO `save_processtime1` (`id`, `point_decimal`) VALUES('5','0.0032867459908127785');

mysql>SELECT MAX(point_decimal) FROM save_processtime;
+-----------------------+
| MAX(point_decimal)    |
+-----------------------+
| 0.1000000021200021011 |
+-----------------------+
```

---

**Other Approach:**

You can save this data into a table with field as **VARCHAR**. and simply get max of the field.

**Dummy Table Structure :**

```
CREATE TABLE `save_processtime` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `point_num` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into `save_processtime` (`id`, `point_num`) values('1','0.0034867459008127785');
insert into `save_processtime` (`id`, `point_num`) values('2','0.0034867459908127785');
insert into `save_processtime` (`id`, `point_num`) values('3','0.0034867459908127001');
insert into `save_processtime` (`id`, `point_num`) values('4','0.1000000021200021011');
insert into `save_processtime` (`id`, `point_num`) values('5','0.0032867459908127785');
```

**Output for max time:**

```
mysql> SELECT MAX(point_num) FROM save_processtime;
+-----------------------+
| MAX(point_num)        |
+-----------------------+
| 0.1000000021200021011 |
+-----------------------+
```

Hope this is what you want! First approach is better than second :)

Comment: I do not think this is a good idea. I prefer numbers treated as numbers.

Comment: Yes you are right! but This is a way you can store decimal numbers in varchar.